# Calling objective-c selector methods through FFI in Ruby

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macos, ffi

Say you want to open a simple alertbox, which in the objective-c universe would be something like:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Alert."];

    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window
                      modalDelegate:self
                     didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                        contextInfo:nil];
```

The beginModalForWindow is defined as a selector method. In apples reference guide it's full name is "beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:"

It's defined in NSAlert.h as:

```
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window modalDelegate:(id)delegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

Now the simple question, how to define this method in ruby ffi?

```
module AppKit
  extend FFI::Library

  # Load the Cocoa framework's binary code
  ffi_lib '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit'

  attach_function :beginSheetModalForWindow, [:pointer,:pointer,:pointer], :bool
end
```

Fails with:

```
An exception occurred running ffi-test.rb
  Function 'beginSheetModalForWindow' not found in [/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit] (FFI::NotFoundError)
```

Comment: Well, the method is really called `beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`(not `beginSheetModalForWindow`), but surely that even isn't the correctly mangled C function name (the class is missing). I doubt it will be that easy. You would also need to pass `self` (a pointer to the object) and `_cmd` (pointer to the selector) as the first two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't.  At least not without a slew of hoop jumping.

`attach_function` does what it says;  it binds a *C function* into the Ruby runtime.   `beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:` is not a C function;  it is a selector.

What you really want to bind is the *implementation of that selector*.

But not really.

What you'd really want to bind is `objc_msgSend` with a type signature that includes all the arguments to that method.  And you'll also need to attach `sel_getUid`.  Oh, and you'll need to attach `objc_lookUpClass`

Then you would do something like (pseudo code):

```
 ... attach objc_msgSend to msgSend with no arguments and object return type ...
 alert = msgSend(msgSend(msgSend(lookupClass("NSAlert"),getUid("alloc")),
           getUid("init")), getUid("autorelease"))

 ... attach objc_msgSend to bs with all the arguments for beginSheetModal....
 bs(alert, getUid("beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo", ... all the arguments ...))
```

Or something like that.

At which point, you've re-invented a very rudimentary form of [MacRuby](http://macruby.org) or [RubyCocoa](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net).